# idiv makes overflow with sign extension

Tags: assembly, x86-64

What goes wrong with IDV here ? I eliminated all the usual suspects; no sign extension and large dividend/small divisor. But still I get `-2147483646` when trying to divide `4` with `2`. (I also printed both rax and rcx before divison and their values are correct).

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.data

outfmt: .asciz  "%d\n"
array:  .int 4,31,5,4

.text

.global main


main:

enter 0,0
xor rcx, rcx
inc rcx 
inc rcx

lea rdi, array
mov rax, [rdi]
cqto
idiv rcx    

lea rdi, outfmt
mov rsi, rax
call printf

leave
ret
```

Comment: `.int` is 4 bytes, but you load 8. You most certainly did **not** eliminate the "large dividend" case. You might want to use `.quad` instead. But then again `%d` also expects 4 bytes, so then maybe switch to 32 bit arithmetic.

Comment: So what exactly did it load besides `4` ? I thought  `[rdi]` takes just 4, so all `rax` has is `4`. Also, doesnt `cqto` just extend the sign up ?

Comment: `mov` into `rax` loads 8 bytes. So it took the `4` **and** the `31` so your dividend was actually `0x0000001F00000004`.

Comment: Ah, I see so it merged both values and treated them as one. So the only solution would be to use 32bit registers ?

Comment: Since you are printing the result with `%d` which again is a 32 bit integer, yeah, using 32 bit operations would make sense.